# Git command to show the value of a branch

Tags: git

I'm looking for a git command like this:

```
git show-branch-value refs/heads/master
cf574d699a8bd67fc0b851cda3452c4d18c4223540a
```

What I want it to do is show the value of the selected branch.

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
git rev-parse refs/heads/master
```

This works for anything (branches, tags, SHAs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git rev-parse refs/heads/your-branch
```

or on remote branches

```
git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/some-remote-branch
```

But you can also just cat the file (if it hasn't been packed - see comment by Dmitry below):

```
cat .git/refs/heads/your-branch
```

Comment: You can "cat .git/refs/heads/your-branch" unless the reference is packed. Otherwise it is listed in .git/packed-refs. So "rev-parse" is more reliable.